# Why there needs to be text after a <br> inside the <th> tag?

Tags: html, encoding, html-table, line-breaks

### *This is a question regarding the behavior of the `<br>` tag when it's inside another tag.*

I'm doing this table where there's a `<thead>` with two `<th>` inside of it: one reads *"name"* and the other one *"last name"*. A `<br>` is inserted between *'last'* and *'name'* to display the second `<th>` in two lines and avoid a longer cell width.

Now that *"last name"* is displayed in two lines, the text in both `<th>` don't start at the same height.

I would like the text in the *"name"* `<th>` to start at the same height than the *"last name"* `<th>`.

- Typing `<th>NAME <br> </th>` does nothing.
- Typing `<th>NAME <br> .</th>` does the desired line break.

Why is that so?

Shouldn't blank spaces count as content if they are between tags and, thus, activate the `<br>` goodness?

How can I achieve two lines in the *"name"* `<th>` without unecessary characters on the second line or without having to style it with CSS?

**check the html and enlighten me**

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="2px">
    <thead>
      <th>NAME <br> </th>
      <th>LAST<br>NAME</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <table border="2px">
    <thead>
      <th>NAME <br> .</th>
      <th>LAST<br>NAME</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm curious about the flawed behavior of the `<br>` when it is inside another tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to put a `&nbsp;` between them that should do what your are looking for.

```
<th>NAME <br>&nbsp;</th>
```

Or you could close the br tag and that should work to

```
<th>NAME <br /> </th>
```

Comment: Thank you, that would solve the problem. But what is actually preventing the <br> to take effect? e.g. I don't need to type <p>Last&nbsp;Name</p> for the blank space to encode properly, I just type <p>Last Name</p>. Why is that so?

Comment: I am going to guess that is just the way the parser parses it. since you dont close the br you could also try <br /> which should work aswell

Comment: I'll have to check more info about parsing, thanks. I thought self-closing tags only needed to be closed in xhtml.

Answer (score 0):

Use either `style="vertical-align:top;"` or `valign="top"` to align it top

```html
<html>

<body>
  <table border="2px">
    <thead>
      <th valign="top">NAME</th>
      <th>LAST<br>NAME</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <table border="2px">
    <thead>
      <th style="vertical-align:top;">NAME</th>
      <th>LAST<br>NAME</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice, I had no idea. Sadly, seems like valign attribute is not supported by HTML5. I could style it with CSS but the question was really about why does the <br> behave like that.

Comment: ok. but what will you do if another column heading comes 4 lines? will you give 3 `<br/>`? not a good Idea right? you have to go with styling in `css` which safe in all scenarios